Do I need to recompile my application while migrating from .Net 4.7.2 to 4.8 for security reasons?
We have a few dozens of C# applications that are compiled for .Net Framework 4.7.2 (some are Web API, others are console applications, others are web forms).
They are all hosted on Windows Servers 2019 and these servers already all have .Net Framework 4.8 installed on them (it was a news to me, I was under impression servers still had 4.7.2). So I guess this means that all our applications, even though compiled with 4.7.2, are already compatible with 4.8
If our only reason for upgrading to 4.8 is for security and to be on the latest supported .Net Framework version - is there anything to be gained by recompiling for 4.8? Or are we automatically covered security-wise just by upgrading .Net Framework to the latest version on the server?
We would rather avoid the work involved in recompilation, testing and deployment. We have no need in any of the new features introduced in 4.8

You only select the minimum version that the target machine must have installed.  It runs on the actual installed version, surely 4.8 or 4.8.1 as provided by Windows Update.  Security has nothing to do with it.   So sure, no need to rebuild.
